# How can I set highlight quote key color in yaml in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml

In VS Code, yaml ksey with quotes display with the same color as values:
[image: qoute yaml key in vscode]

I want it to display like in different colors(like in idea):
[image]

How can I get this style of yaml highlight?

Comment: Please provide a code block of that yaml to help others reproduce the issue. ([mre])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` action to open [the Scope Inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector). Then click on the token you want to inspect. Then find out its textmate scopes. For example, for the unquoted keys, you'll probably see:

```
entity.name.tag.yaml
string.unquoted.plain.out.yaml
```

Pick appropriate textmate scopes, and then use them in token colour customizations like so:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Colour Theme Name Goes Here]": { // TODO: put your colour theme name here
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "string.unquoted.plain.out.yaml", // or whichever one is appropriate
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO: paste the colour you want here
                }
            },
            ... // TODO
        ],
    }
},
```

If you want the same colour customizations to take effect for all colour themes, then just don't wrap it in a block with the name of your colour theme.

See also [the docs for creating your own colour theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme).

Comment: Thank you. Althougth this does not work because vscode cannot recognize "text with qoutes" as a yaml key, this may be the correct direction for this.

Comment: @once I noticed the same thing as you - that vs code sees quoted keys as quoted strings rather than keys. Did you end up finding a solution?